# Problema al pasar un Json mediante onclick a javscript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, json

estoy tratando de enviar un array mediante onclick en una funcion, para eso uso json. Pero me marca un error de syntaxis cuando lo mando.

Por cierto una ves que recibo el json,como puedo hacer para recorrer sus datos?
Saludos.

Error por consola.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo:

```
<td>
                          <select id="OBJ<?php echo $idCriterio;?>" name="COE" onchange="FunSumT(<?php echo json_encode($criterio); ?> )">
                            <option value='0'>0</option>
                            <option value='1'>1</option>
                            <option value='2'>2</option>
                            <option value='3'>3</option>
                            <option value='4'>4</option>
                            <option value='5'>5</option>
                          </select>
                        </td>
```

Codigo de mi funcion js

```
function FunSumT(criterio){
                      var array=JSON.stringify(criterio);
                      console.log(array);
       }
```

Comment: Si, es por mis datos de mi tabla, por eso, pero la solucion que llege es que le tuve que quitar las comillas " y en ves de eso ponerle apostrofes ' y ahí si me funciono ... pero la verdad no sé por que jeje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que tal? Por lo que puedo ver en la imagen que compartís (ya que no esta la linea entera que no sea en desarrollo). Que el problema que tenes son las comillas. Proba lo siguiente:

```
 onchange='FunSumT(<?php echo json_encode($criterio); ?> )'
```

Ya que al dejar comillas dobles y el json también las utiliza se te rompe todo.

Probalo y comentame si fue la solución.

Un consejo que te puedo dar ya que vi en las etiquetas que pusiste que usas jquery. Que antes de poner la función en el html hagas todo desde un javascript. Para que quede mas ordenado y se te sea mas fácil identificar errores. Por ejemplo hacer algo así:

```
$('select[name="COE"]').on('change', function() {
    console.log("Aca escribis el codigo que necesites");
});
```

Si necesitas que en  tenga datos entonces los agregas de la siguiente manera:

```
<select data-id="<?=$idCriterio;?>" data-ejemplo="test">
```

Un ejemplo de como obtener dichos datos puede ser:

```
var id=$('select').data("id");
```

En el caso que este html se agregue después del momento que cargo el JS. podes  usar la funcion bind() y unbind().
Te dejo la documentacion de las mismas a continuación para no hacer muy extenso esto.
[Jquery .bind()](https://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias me sirvio de ayuda, si justamente el problema era con las comillas y las solucione. Ahora si logro mandar el json a mi funcion de js, pero ahora tengo un problema, como lo puedo recorrer? disculpa no tengo mucho conocimiento con json.

Comment: No pasa nada! asi se aprende. Tenes un json la forma mas comoda de correrlo creo que es con un foreach.
Podes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:
$.each(myArray, function( index, value ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + value );
});